# ShinyApp for R keeps "stealing" my image output

Tags: r, image, shiny

So here's the catch, I'm working on a Shiny app that's presenting data about Thailand provinces so I decided to color different areas of a map depending on the selected provinces [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7SjD.png).

This is my code :

```
//This is in my fluidPage()
    imageOutput("map1")

//This is in my function(input,output)
    output$map1 <- renderImage({
    list(
        src=str_c("images/",str_replace_all(input$province1,pattern=" ",replacement="_"),".png"),
        width=300,
        height=400)
  })
```

My "images" folder is in the same folder as the R file, I also made a "www" folder.

At first I stored my images in the "www" folder and they disappeared after I used them, so my guess was the app was storing input images in this folder and deleted them afterwards. I proceeded to put the pictures in a "images" folder thinking I would get rid of the disappearing files but it didn't fix anything :(

Did I get it right about the "www" folder ? Should I store my pictures in a different folder and "refill" the "images" folder after each use ? Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: The documentation says that it deletes the file. Change that via the `deleteFile` argument if you want something else. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html

Comment: Oh ok I see, thank you